# Rational points on a curve of genus $\geq 2$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Is there any relationship between the number of the rational points on a curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ of genus $\geq 2$  and its Jacobian?

Comment: Are you working over a number field?  Are you working over a finite field?

Comment: The number of rational points on a curve defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ (and more generally, a number field) can be bounded in terms of the genus and the Mordell-Weil rank of the Jacobian, provided said rank is sufficiently small compared to the genus. More recent work in non-abelian Chabauty can extend this further to the case when the rank of the Neron-Severi group is large. See for example https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1476450482

Comment: There are conjectures, and for certain families theorems, saying that $$\#C(\mathbb Q)\le \kappa(g)^{1+\operatorname{rank} J(\mathbb Q)}.$$ Here $g$ is the genus of $C$. However, the Bombieri-Lang conjecture (rational points are not Zariski dense on varieties of general type) implies a stronger uniform bound $\#C(\mathbb Q)\le\kappa'(g)$. Is this what you had in mind?